# Client and server applications can't communicate running on a container and host?

Tags: docker, networking

I have a client and server applications. The server listens on TCP `localhost:3344` address  and the client send message to `localhost:3344`. This works fine when running them on the same host.

If the server is running on a docker container and the client is running on host, the server doesn't receive any messages. Not sure how I can setup the networking so that the container listens on host's localhost. I try the following:

```
docker run -it --expose 3344 -p 127.0.0.1:3344:3344 run-server
```

Comment: Is your server listening on 0.0.0.0 or localhost? Because if your server is listening on localhost, then it will only listen the requests originating from the IP address of the docker container not from outside. Your docker container's IP is not same as your host IP.

Comment: The server is listening on localhost not on 0.0.0.0

Comment: Then you should make your server to listen on `0.0.0.0`. Since you have specified `-p 127.0.0.1:3344:3344` in your docker run command, docker creates an Iptable rule that only forwards packets from 127.0.0.1:3344(host) to your server container's 3344 port. So rest assured, no one other than your host can send request to your server running inside docker container.

Comment: You only need to run `docker run -p 3344:3344 run-server` and you should be able to access `localhost:3344` to communicate with server app.

Comment: @Cylops Now it works. Could explain why 0.0.0.0 works but not localhost?

Comment: @Cory  In the same way that if you have a server listening on `localhost` on your computer, nothing on your external network can connect. If you have something in a container listening on `localhost`, nothing external can connect.

Comment: @Cory Each container has it's own loopback interface that resolves in the container as `localhost`.   So `localhost` on the docker host is not the same `localhost` in a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will just do the job for you:

```
docker run -it -p 3344:3344 <docker repository name> run-server
```